# Bochner integral on non complete space

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, operator-theory, banach-spaces, complete-spaces

Let $X_0=(X,\|\cdot\|_0)$ be a Banach space and $X_1=(X,\|\cdot\|_1)$ a normed vector space (not complete) such that there is a constant $c>0$ such that
\begin{align*}
\|\cdot\|_1 \leq c\|\cdot\|_0
\end{align*}
Now given an operator $T$ satisfying for some $\alpha >0$ and $p>1$

\begin{align*}
\int_0^\alpha \|(Tf)(t)\|_1^pdt \leq M\|f\|_{L^p([0,\alpha],X_0)}
\end{align*}
for some $M>0$ and all $f\in L^p([0,\alpha],X_0)$.

It is to be noted that, in my knowledge, we cannot define the space $L^p([0,\alpha],X_1)$ since $X_1$ is not complete. Now my question is : can I see that $T\in \mathcal{L}(L^p([0,\alpha],X_0))$?

Comment: The estimate suggests only $T\in \mathcal(L^p(X_0), L^p(X_1))$ - if the latter space would make sense.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I was thinking if I can obtain a result juste like the one obtained here [link](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2034534?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents) (first lemma).